# Does casting remove endian dependency in C/C++?

Tags: c, casting, variable-assignment, endianness, dereference

i.e. if we cast a C or C++ unsigned char array named arr as (unsigned short*)arr and then assign to it, is the result the same independent of machine endianness?

Side note - I saw the discussion on IBM and elsewhere on SO with example:

```
unsigned char endian[2] = {1, 0};
short x;
x = *(short *) endian;
```

...stating that the value of x will depend on the layout of endian, and hence the endianness of the machine.  That means dereferencing an array is endian-dependent, but what about assigning to it?

```
*(short*) endian = 1;
```

Are all future short-casted dereferences then guaranteed to return 1, regardless of endianness?

---

After reading the responses, I wanted to post some context:

In this struct

```
struct pix { 
    unsigned char r; 
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b; 
    unsigned char a; 
    unsigned char y[2]; 
 };
```

replacing unsigned char y[2] with unsigned short y makes no individual difference, but if I make an array of these structs and put that in another struct, then I've noticed that the size of the container struct tends to be higher for the "unsigned short" version, so, since I intend to make a large array, I went with unsigned char[2] to save space overhead.  I'm not sure why, but I imagine it's easier to align the uchar[2] in memory.

Because I need to do a ton of math with that variable y, which is meant to be a single short-length numerical value, I find myself casting to short a lot just to avoid individually accessing the uchar bytes... sort of a fast way to avoid ugly byte-specific math, but then I thought about endianness and whether my math would still be correct if I just cast everything like

```
*(unsigned short*)this->operator()(x0, y0).y = (ySum >> 2) & 0xFFFF;
```

...which is a line from a program that averages 4-adjacent-neighbors in a 2-D array, but the point is that I have a bunch of these operations that need to act on the uchar[2] field as a single short, and I'm trying to find the lightest (i.e. without an endian-based if-else statement every time I need to access or assign), endian-independent way of working with the short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all future dereferences will return `1` as well: As `1` is in range of type `short`, it will end up in memory unmodified and won't change behind your back once it's there.

However, the code itself violates effective typing: It's illegal to access an `unsigned char[2]` as a `short`, and may raise a `SIGBUS` if your architecture doesn't support unaligned access and you're particularly unlucky.

However, character-wise access of any object is always legal, and a portable version of your code looks like this:

```
short value = 1;
unsigned char *bytes = (unsigned char *)&value;
```

How `value` is stored in memory is of course still implementation-defined, ie you can't know what the following will print without further knowledge about the architecture:

```
assert(sizeof value == 2); // check for size 2 shorts
printf("%i %i\n", bytes[0], bytes[1]);
```

Comment: I'd say it raises `SIGBUS` if you're *lucky*. Some ARM chips would silently read or write an "incorrect" value on an unaligned access.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the portability suggestion.  In this struct struct pix {
 unsigned char r;
 unsigned char g;
 unsigned char b;
 unsigned char a;
 unsigned char y[2];
}; replacing char y[2] with short y makes no individual difference, but if I make an array of these structs and put that in another struct, then I've noticed that the size of the container struct tends to be higher for the short version, so since I intend to make a large array, I went with char[2].  but since I need to do a ton of math with that variable, I find myself casting to short a lot...

Comment: @Cindeselia: You should probably ask a separate question about those size differences, and show the complete code for "another struct" as well. If there's a size difference then it should be possible to get the smaller size *and* have `y` be a short, either by re-ordering the members or using compiler-specific directives to control struct packing and alignment.

Comment: @Cindeselia: you're trading speed for size as the access to `y` as a `short` will be mis-aligned, which is more costly on most architectures; however, having smaller structures is more cache friendly, which might or might not offset this cost; it's probably a good idea to ask another question as Steve suggested...

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to strict pointer aliasing it's undefined behaviour, so it might be anything. If you'd do the same with a union however the answer is no, the result is dependent on machine endianness.

Comment: "it's undefined behaviour, so it might be anything" - true, but in practice I believe that implementations universally do support aliasing `unsigned char` as another type (they're *required* to support aliasing another type as `unsigned char`, of course), because otherwise it's pretty much impossible to implement `malloc`, or for user code to implement its own "memory allocators" that divide up a big array of characters into smaller chunks used for other types. So the only thing to worry about is alignment.

Comment: @Steve: while what you describe is true, strictly speaking, violating effective typing *is* a compiler extension; also, keep in mind that it's the programmer's responsibility to take care of alignment requirements, which the compiler transparently handles for you if you use the union hack...

Comment: Agreed. As another option: if you use `memcpy` both to read and write, then there's no violation of strict aliasing and it doesn't matter how the char array is aligned.

Answer (score 3):

Each possible value of `short` has a so-called "object representation"[*], which is a sequence of byte values. When an object of type `short` holds that value, the bytes of the object hold that sequence of values.

You can think of endianness as just being one of the ways in which the object representation is implementation-dependent: does the byte with the lowest address hold the most significant bits of the value, or the least significant?

Hopefully this answers your question. Provided you've safely written a valid object representation of `1` as a short into some memory, when you read it back from the same memory you'll get the same value again, regardless of what the object representation of `1` actually is in that implementation. And in particular regardless of endianness. But as the others say, you do have to avoid undefined behavior.

[*] Or possibly there's more than one object representation for the same value, on exotic architectures.